# Projecting a point onto line in Matlab, bad precision?

Tags: matlab, geometry, linear-algebra

I wrote a function in Matlab that projects a point P onto line that goes through points V1 and V2.

Let's call the projected point P'. 
P' = alfa*V1 + (1-alfa)*V2

The function returns alfa and the distance between P and P'.

```
function [alfa, dist] = ProjectPoint(P, V2, V1)

d1 = pdist2(P, V1);
d2 = pdist2(P, V2);
d  = pdist2(V1, V2);

t = ((d1*d1 - d2*d2)/d) + d;
t = t/2;

alfa = t/d;
dist = sqrt( d1*d1 - t*t );
```

The function looks correct and returns right results for simple inputs.

But sometimes the result has an error that is not acceptable. For example, for

```
V1 = [40.1587, 50.7355, 36.00];
V2 = [36.5079, 45.0980, 33.00];
P  = [36.5079, 45.0980, 39.00];
```

My results are:             alfa = 0.6673, dist = 5.4783.

And the right results are:  alfa = 0.6064, dist = 5.4966.

Why does it happens? How I can improve it?

Comment: I also get `dist = 5.4783` with `v = (V2-V1)/norm(V2-V1); Q = dot(P-V1,v)*v+V1; dist = norm(P-Q)`. Your value seems to be correct

Comment: It doesn't solve your precision issue but may be able to improve your algorithm with a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273991/finding-the-point-of-intersection-on-a-3d-line-perpendicular-to-a-target-point/31274489#comment50543389_31274489). It is very similar to what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your values seem to be correct. Here's an independent computation:

```
V1 = [40.1587, 50.7355, 36.00];
V2 = [36.5079, 45.0980, 33.00];
P  = [36.5079, 45.0980, 39.00];
v = (V2-V1)/norm(V2-V1); %// normalized vector from V1 to V2
Q = dot(P-V1,v)*v+V1; %// projection of P onto line from V1 to V2
dist = norm(P-Q);
alfa = (Q(1)-V1(1))/(V2(1)-V1(1));
```

Results:

```
dist =
    5.4783
alfa =
    0.6673
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the function I compare my results to, is wrong itself.